# Starting a slave from behind master

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication

We're moving to a different cloud provider so need to migrate our database with as little downtime as possible.

Here's our current setup:

```
master
└───slave1
└───slave2    
└───slaveBackup
```

A dump of `slaveBackup` was imported into our new master database, `newMaster`. `slaveBackup` logs changes to its bin logs using `log-slave-updates` and `binlog_do_db` to only log the correct database which is identically named throughout.

To reduce downtime we now want to add `newMaster` as a slave to `slaveBackup`, thus creating the following chain while we migrate:

```
master
└───slave1
└───slave2    
└───slaveBackup
    └───newMaster
        └───newSlave1
        └───newSlave2
```

`newMaster` is replicated as intended to `newSlave1` and `newSlave2`, all are identical.

We recorded the bin log file and position on `slaveBackup` made immediately after the dump and used this to add `newMaster` as a slave of `slaveBackup`:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
    MASTER_HOST = 'slaveBackup',
    MASTER_USER = 'slave',
    MASTER_PASSWORD = '',
    MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mariadb-bin.00000X',
    MASTER_LOG_POS = X;
```

Starting the slave worked perfectly and in time using `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` we could see it catch up to its master.

**Here's where it gets weird. Despite the slave `newMaster` crunching through the bin logs, no rows are being inserted into the new database. What's weirder during this time `Seconds_Behind_Master` was always 0.**

The logs were definitely being processed as the slave user is different on `newMaster` ('slave'@'X.X.X.X') vs `slaveBackup` ('slave'@'Y.Y.Y.Y') and a moderation made after the dump of this user caused `newMaster` to error and required `SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;` to recover.

Now the slave is fully caught up with master in terms of bin log file and position yet not data has been inserted into its database.

Why is this?

The bin logs on `slaveBackup` definitely have the correct `USE DATABASENAME;` statements before each insert/update, hence why I'm completely stumped.

To clarify the replication chain:

```
master -> slaveBackup -> newMaster -> newSlave1/2
```

Comment: It is unclear what steps you took to make newMaster from slaveBackup.  And it is unclear which "recorded the bin log file and position" you used.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames for the questions. slaveBackup is still very much live, when the dump was made we used the flush logs flag to ensure a new bin log file was created. This file and its position was what was added to newMaster as its master

Comment: Did you stop the slave during the dump?  Else you don't know how the binlog and dump align.

Comment: We used --flush-logs so the logs were rotated at the time of the dump, in all honesty though ACID isn't our issue right now: why the newMaster churned through the logs yet didn't make any writes is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the server IDs conflicted further down the chain which caused the issue of the bin logs syncing but not replicating

**Warning to all, make sure all your server IDs are unique!**